# array of void pointer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use strtok to break up a string and push into a stack. could be integers or '+' or '-' signs. i have traced the problem to the push function, and void ** a is a void pointer to array.

It prints out garbage value when i did the  `cout << getVP(a) << " " ;`

my getVP function

```
int Stack::getVP (void* a) const
{
return *(static_cast <char *>(a));
}
```

Please don't ask me why i'm not using `std::Stack`. I'm not tasked to do so yeah got to do it in array.

edited: made some changes to my codes, right now when i store it in void * temp, it doesn't print out the right input. anyone?

Comment: Things look fishy here. Why are you using `void *`?

Comment: *"could be integers or `'+'` or `'-'` signs"* - that's not a reason to use `void*`

Comment: well, my lecturer gave us in this format.

Comment: Where is your constructor?

Comment: Use template, `void*` is an ancient evil

Comment: Lecturer learned about classes but still thinks in C...

Comment: @EdHeal my constructor? i just had like int top = -1;

Comment: @aleguna - Even in C you do not need `void *`. A `struct/union` combo would work.

Comment: `while(std::cin >> my_string) { ...` would make your code cleaner and safer in 1 blow.

Comment: edited my codes. any idea why still doesn't work? still got to stick to void * though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all over the place:

This code is incorrect - comments are corrects/notes:

```
void Stack::push (char* temp)
{
   a = new void * [MAX]; // Assume a is a member variable of type 'void **' it will
                         // be a memory leak for starters. Why not make a an array
                         // or char *. i.e.
                         // char *a[MAX];
                         // or better string string a[MAX];

   if (!isFull())
   {
      top = top + 1;    
      *a = temp;        // This is incorrect - should be a[top] = temp;
                        // Possibly want to duplicate temp here

   cout << getVP(a) << " " ; // Why make this complicated function
                             // Just cout << a[lop] << endl; would do

    ++a;                     // Not needs and confuses things
   }

}
```